# Accessing controls in Master page from content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages, content-pages

I am trying to access control in Master page from Content page(Asp.net) using javascript like this

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%=((Label)Master.FindControl("lbl")).ClientID %>').value);
```

control in Master page is as follow,

```
 <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="one"></asp:Label>
```

But unfortunately it is not working. I am getting undefined value

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you get an `Exception` from .NET or an `undefined` value in the alert? The [`FindControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) method is not recursive, so unless your `lbl` control is a direct children of `Master`, it won't be found.

Comment: so what is the solution? how can I correct it?

Comment: I get undefined value

Comment: Why you don't use a pure javascript solution? jQuery helps you a lot: `$("#parent").find(".contrl-class-name").val(); `. If you give us more information, we'd give you better answer.

Comment: I know it works, I have worked on project where it's working fine. I am just missing something that's why I asking for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that you are actually accessing the `.value` field of the element that the `<asp:Label />` control generates, which is a `<span></span>`. This type of element won't return anything for the `.value` attribute. If you are actually trying to access its text then use:

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%=((Label)Master.FindControl("lbl")).ClientID %>').innerText);
```

or

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%=((Label)Master.FindControl("lbl")).ClientID %>').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a master page is a naming container, hence the client id of the control receives a prefix which is the id of the naming container.
Using JavaScript, it is easily solvable:

```
var elm = document.querySelector('[id$="lbl"]');
```

$= means, ends with.

Answer (score 0):

Include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in your page and use this script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#lbl").text());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me:(Check the below code)

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%=(Master.FindControl("lbl")).ClientID %>').innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `getElementById` didn't work for me. The following can be used instead:

```
$find('<%=((Label)Master.FindControl("lbl")).ClientID %>');
```